# How to compare two logarithmic functions using derivatives?

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

I have two expressions: $\log_2 5$ and $\log_3 13$.

And I need to determine which expression is greater using exactly derivatives and not having a calculator.

I know that $(y = \log_2 5)'$ = $\frac{1}{5ln2}$ and $(y = \log_3 13)'$ = $\frac{1}{13ln3}$

But what are the further steps(algorithm) in such cases to determine what is greater?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Derivative of a constant is zero. To compare both these you can use properties of logarithmic function, first make their bases equal then see that logarithmic function is monotonic increasing.

Comment: Did the problem composer explicitly require that derivatives be employed?

Comment: I need any possible solution to the problems of such kind(if possible derivatives) excluding the way of making the bases equal and calculator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addendum added to respond to the comment of
vortexsf24.

---

A very similar problem was posted on MathSE recently.  Another reviewer found the following solution that I would not have thought of.  If I remember correctly, it was Dietrich Burde; I could be mistaken about who found the solution.  I can't find the original posting; it may have been deleted.

You can show, with minimal calculation (without a calculator) that

$$3 \times \log_2(5) < 7 < 3 \times \log_3(13).$$

This simplifies to showing that

$$\log_2\left(5^3\right) < 7 < \log_3\left(13^3\right).\tag1 $$

In (1) above, the LHS inequality is fairly easy.  Simply notice that $~5^3 = 125 < 128 = 2^7.~$  So, since $~2^7 > 125,~$ you must have that $~\displaystyle \log_2\left(5^3\right)~$ must be $~< 7.$

In (1) above, the RHS inequality is more difficult, but can still be confirmed by pencil and paper (again without a calculator).  Simply verify that

$$3^7 = 2187 < 2197 = 13^3.$$

So, since $~3^7 < 13^3,~$ you must have that $~\displaystyle \log_3\left(13^3\right)~$ is $~> 7.$

---

$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$

Responding to the comment of vortexsf24.

> Thanks, but I already know this solution. As I wrote in comments I have a task to do it differently.

"I need any possible solution to the problems of such kind(if possible derivatives) excluding the way of making the bases equal and calculator"

My answer did not *make the bases equal*.

Also, it isn't really appropriate to try to use derivatives to attack this type of problem.  Both sides of the inequality are **constants**.  The derivative of a constant is $~0.~$

One approach for trying to *force-fit* the use of derivatives onto this problem is as follows:

The problem can be restated as :

Prove that

$$\frac{\log(5)}{\log(2)} < \frac{\log(13)}{\log(3)},$$

where $~\log(x)~$ refers to the *natural logarithm*.

This can be re-stated as

Prove that $$\frac{\log(5) \times \log(3)}{\log(2)} < \log(13). \tag2 $$

Then, using (2) above as the starting point of your analysis, you would set

$$f(x) = \log(x) - \frac{\log(5) \times \log(3)}{\log(2)}. \tag3 $$

It is easy to see that on $~\Bbb{R^+},~$ since $~f'(x) = \dfrac{1}{x} > 0,~$ the function $~f(x)~$ is strictly increasing.

Further, since $~\log(1) = 0,~$ you know that $~f(1) < 0.~$  Therefore, since $~\lim_{x\to\infty} \log(x) = \infty,~$ you also know that $~f(x)~$ must cross the $~x$-axis exactly once, for $~x \in (1, +\infty).$

So, the problem is reduced to determining whether the (sole) root of the equation $~f(x) = 0~$ is less than $~13,~$ equal to $~13,~$ or greater than $~13.~$

Personally, I don't see how this approach gets anywhere.  You know that :

- $\displaystyle f(1) = - \frac{\log(5) \times \log(3)}{\log(2)}.$
- $f'(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}, ~f''(x) = \dfrac{-1}{x^2}, f'''(x) = \dfrac{2}{x^3}, \cdots $

I don't see any way of using these insights to determine whether the *rate of increase* of $~f(x)~$ is *slowed down enough* so that $~f(x)~$ crosses the $~x$-axis before $~x=13,~$ rather than after.

Comment: Thanks, but I already know this solution. As I wrote in comments I have a task to do it differently.

Comment: @vortexsf24 See the Addendum that I have just added to the end of my answer.